# VSCode: How to auto-complete React component className in scss file

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

As title, I've tried plugin like [HTML to CSS autocompletion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion)
 and it works on `.html` file, for example:

`index.html`

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div class="sections"></div>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Then in my `.scss` file the auto-complete for `.sections` works:

```
.App {
   .sec  /* Pressing <Tab> at the position following `c` will 
            trigger auto-complete. */
}
```

```
.App {
   .sections /* The result. */
}
```

while this will not work for React component:

```
import "./app.scss"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Topbar/>
      <div className="testing"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the `./app.scss`:

```
.App {
   .tes /* Pressing <Tab> will not trigger auto-complete. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SCSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-scss)] with [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion) & [HTML Class Suggestions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndersEAndersen.html-class-suggestions)

Comment: It doesn't work. Do I have to modify some settings in the Settings of vscode?